# Getting Entity Framework migration error with enum

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have an entity and an enum like this:

```
public class RequestType
{
    public Guid RequestTypeId { get; set; }
    public RequestActionEnum Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Request> Requests { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the enum `RequestActionEnum`:

```
public enum RequestActionEnum
{
    New,
    Update,
    Archive
}
```

I am doing database migrations with Entity Framework Core using this code:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
        modelBuilder.Entity<RequestType>().HasData(
            new RequestType { RequestTypeId = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = RequestActionEnum.New },
            new RequestType { RequestTypeId = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = RequestActionEnum.Update },
            new RequestType { RequestTypeId = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = RequestActionEnum.Archive }
            );
  }
```

But while updating the database using `Update-Database`, I get this error:

> Column "Name" cannot be cast automatically to type integer

I am using Entity Framework Core 3.0 and code-first approach and I am not sure why I am getting this error.

Could any one please suggest any idea about this issue?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the datatype of the `Name` column in your database?

Comment: it is enum i am using this for creating database and code first approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue that EntityFramework doesn't play well with enum values. I don't know that this works with code-first, but I've had success with mapping column values to enums with something like this. In your entity (POCO):

```
[NotMapped]
public RequestActionEnum Name
{
     get { return (RequestActionEnum)NameValue; }
     set { NameValue = (int)value; }
}

[Column("Name")]
public int NameValue { get; set; }
```

It's not the most elegant solution, but it will probably work.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to store all enums as strings using a [value converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions). Do you need to explicitly specify that your enums are stored as numbers?